# Erlang pass-by-reference nuances

Tags: erlang, pass-by-reference

```
9> A = lists:seq(1,10).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
13> Fn = fun (L) -> [0|L] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.90072148>
14> Fn(A).
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
15> A.
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

If erlang internally passes by reference ([see this](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-April/026010.html)), why does the value of A not reflect the change?

What fundamental am I missing about **passing-by-reference** or **erlang**?

Comment: You are not assigning to `L`, you are creating a new list with `[0|L]`.

Comment: All variables in Erlang immutable ,so you cannot change the value of L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a list is a recursive construction of the form L=[Head|Tail] where Head is any valid erlang term and Tail should be a list (if it is something else L is called an improper list, out of the scope of this discussion).

Saying that L is passed as a reference means that:

- it is not necessary to make a copy of the list in the function parameters (good for the process stack :o);
- the function returns a value, it never modify any parameter;
- and in your particular case, it is even not necessary to make a copy of A to create the returned list. As the variable are not mutable, if you write B = Fn(A), then B will contain A, it will be exactly [0|A].

Comment: Just want to add one small thing. I think main reason you are having problem is because you are thinking an erlang list as an array in other languages. But this is not the case. Erlang list is exactly what you would call a linked list in data structures. So L = [Head|Tail] is a node of linked list that has Head as head value and Tail as next value. I hope that would help.